# having problem with db_or() and LIKE clause in drupal 7

Tags: database

I am trying to retrieve data from db with INNER JOIN.

I need the following query executed from drupal's `db_select()`, query is in normal format :

```
SELECT uo.* , uop.data FROM `uc_orders` AS uo 
INNER JOIN `uc_order_products` AS uop ON uo.order_id = uop.order_id 
WHERE ( 
  (
     uop.data LIKE '%mfp_donation%'
  ) 
  OR (
     uop.data LIKE '%scholar_donation%'
  ) 
  OR (
     uop.data LIKE '%reunion%'
  )
)
```

I already tried in drupal, the process is following :

```
$query = db_select('uc_orders', 'uo')
    ->fields('uo')
    ->fields('uop', array('data'));

$alias = $query->join('uc_order_products', 'uop', "uo.order_id = uop.order_id");

$order = $query->condition(db_or()
       ->condition($alias . '.data', '%mfp_donaiton%', 'LIKE')
       ->condition($alias . '.data', '%scholar_donaiton%', 'LIKE')
       ->condition($alias . '.data', '%reunion%', 'LIKE')
    )
    ->execute()
    ->fetchObject();
```

All the process is working fine, but the problem is when i execute/fetch the results then i only get the output for `->condition($alias . '.data', '%reunion%', 'LIKE')` . I mean i only get the `%reunion%` part. The first two conditions is not executing i think.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`dpq()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--devel--devel.module/function/dpq/7) to inspect your query.
Your query looks good, but I suspect that there's a small error in your condition. You put `donaiton`, shouldn't it be `donation` ?

Comment: Really very very thanks to you for answering. I have also figured out the problem just after i posted this problem. :)